# How to load a Yii2 object into inputs using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, yii2

I have generated my model data, using:

```
public function actionGetDatosProducto()
{
    \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    if (($model = Producto::findOne($id)) !== null) {
        return $model;
    } else {
        echo '';
    }
}
```

So I have my JSON object, with its properties:

```
Object {Idproducto: 65, producto: "Meoe", fraccion: "1111", Idcte: 1}
```

Is there a one-line that I can use, so the four values of the JSON response are assigned automatically via javascript to the model inputs on the view, like:

```
$.post(url, {
    id: idModel,
}, function (data) {
    //data is the object with attributes
    $(form).load(data);
}, 'json');
```

in order to avoid the manual input-by-input assign:

```
$('#producto-idproducto').val(data.Idproducto);
$('#producto-producto').val(data.producto);
$('#producto-fraccion').val(data.fraccion);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I used two functions within a Javascript object to accomplish the task, using the following code:

```
toDash: function (modelName) {
    modelName = modelName.substr(0, 1).toLowerCase() + modelName.substr(1);
    return modelName.replace(/([A-Z])/g, function($1){return "-"+$1.toLowerCase();});
},
fillAttributesToFields: function (modelName, data) {
    var modelNameDash = this.toDash(modelName);
    for (attribute in data) {
        $('#'+modelNameDash+'-'+attribute.toLowerCase()).val(data[attribute]);
    }
}
```

That code automatically fills the model data into the form, coming from an AJAX request.

I am unsure as if there is a way to do it with functions provided by the framework, but those two functions worked for me.